# How to put distinct buttons in Angular mat-table?

Tags: arrays, angular, button, angular-material

I'm using angular mat table to display an array of data like below with simple sorting.  The final column is a column of buttons. I'd like to have distinct buttons in each row that route to a different component.

[Array as a table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGBRT.jpg)

```
  <!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let device"> {{device.name}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- SerialNo Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="serialNo">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef > SerialNo </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let device"> {{device.serialNo}} </td>
  </ng-container>

<!-- Button Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
    <th mat-header-cell  *matHeaderCellDef > Actions </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" >
      <button mat-button routerLinkActive="list-item-active" routerLink="/device1" >View</button>
    </td>
```

my component.ts is like this.

```
export interface Devices {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  serialNo: number;
}
//An Array of device1
const DEVICES: Devices[] = [
  {position: 1, name: 'Device 1', serialNo: 135421},
  {position: 2, name: 'Device 2', serialNo: 125240},
  {position: 3, name: 'Device 3', serialNo: 124350},
  {position: 4, name: 'Device 4', serialNo: 124500},
  {position: 5, name: 'Device 5', serialNo: 145620},
];

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'serialNo', 'actions'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(DEVICES);

  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }
```

How would I go about adding distinct buttons in each row that use routerLink to route to different components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to redirect each link to a different *angular* component or do you want to redirect each link to the same angular component (for example, a *device detail* component), but with different url and device information (like redirecting to '/device/1', 'device/2' etc..)?

If the latter is the case, suppose you want to redirect each device to an angular route '/device-detail/:id', where *id* is the identification of the device. For simplicity, suppose *id* is the *serialNo*. So you just need to change the button declaration. Substitute `routerLink="/device1"` for `[routerLink]="['/device-detail', device.serialNo]"` (I also changed `*matCellDef="let row"` to `*matCellDef="let device"`):

```html
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let device" >
   <button mat-button routerLinkActive="list-item-active" [routerLink]="['/device-detail', device.serialNo]" >View</button>
</td>
```

Comment: Yes thats exactly what I was trying to do. Thanks for the help!